Importing an excel spreadsheets into access db
I am using a access db, I have code that exports the db out to an excel spreadsheet for a backup. I have been searching & working with code to import that excel spreadsheet back into the access db. Right now the code will create the tables and imports one row of the spreadsheet, which is the headers. I can see the data from the spreadsheet inside datagridview, so I know its pulling all of it, but it only inserts one row into the db.
I don't know what I am missing to get the rest of the data back into the db.
I expected all of the information in each sheet, within the exported spreadsheet to be pulled into the db.
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Excel connection string
                string excelConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/temp/TestFolder/Test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'";
            // Access connection string
                string accessConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/temp/TestFolder/TestDatabase.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

                using (OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnStr))
                using (OleDbConnection accessConn = new OleDbConnection(accessConnStr))
                {
                    excelConn.Open();
                    accessConn.Open();

                    // Get the list of sheet names from Excel
                    DataTable excelSchema = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);



                    foreach (DataRow row in excelSchema.Rows)
                    {
                        string sheetName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        // Remove the trailing $ sign from the sheet name
                        if (sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                        {
                            // Import data from the sheet to Access table
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}]", excelConn))
                            {
                                DataTable excelData = new DataTable();
                                adapter.Fill(excelData);

                                // Create the corresponding table in Access (assuming the table doesn't exist)
                                string createTableQuery = $"CREATE TABLE [{sheetName.Replace("$", "")}] (";

                                foreach (DataColumn column in excelData.Columns)
                                {
                                    createTableQuery += $"[{column.ColumnName}] TEXT, ";
                                }


                            try // Catch if the table name exist already in database
                            {
                                createTableQuery = createTableQuery.TrimEnd(',', ' ') + ")";
                                OleDbCommand createTableCommand = new OleDbCommand(createTableQuery, accessConn);
                                createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Insert data into Access table
                                using (OleDbDataAdapter accessAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName.Replace("$", "")}]", accessConn))
                                using (OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(accessAdapter))
                                {
                                    accessAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
                                    accessAdapter.Update(excelData);
                                }
                            }


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Data imported successfully.");
            }


Why don't you just copy the Access file as a backup?

Does this answer your question? Import Excel to Access with c#
